# How to describe relationship among records in the same table with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, nullable

In EF i need to describe the following relationship:

a company may have many Locations, like

```
headquarter         <= main location 
      plant      ----+
      warehouse      |
      store-1        +----> child Locations
      store-2        |
      store-n    ----+
```

So I need a mainLocationID in the Location model, so that I can

1) given the main location I can access all its child locations

2) given a child location I can find its main location.

So I tried to do the following:

```
public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool flagMainLocation { get; set; }

    public int? mainLocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> ChildLocations { get; set; }
}
```

and in my dbcontext

```
public class myappContext : DbContext
{
    public myappContext() : base("myappContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
                            .HasOptional(l => l.ChildLocations)
                            .WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey(l => l.mainLocationID);
    }
}
```

Now I'm stuck because as I try to scaffold a controller for the Location class I get the following error

```
"myapp.DAL.Location_ChildLocations:: Multiplicity conflicts with 
the referential constraint in Role 'Location_ChildLocations_Target' 
in relationship 'Location_ChildLocations'. Because all of the 
properties in the Dependant Role are non-nullable, multiplicity 
of the Principal Role must be '1'."
```

I'm not expert enough with EF to decrypt this error message. 
Is there anyone who can tell me what is wrong with this configuration?

I would also like to be able to get the main location in this way

```
Location myChildLocation = db.Locations.Find(some_location_id);
Location mainLocation = myChildLocation.mainLocation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasMany(l => l.ChildLocations)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(l => l.mainLocationID);
```

Comment: Exactly the same error message. I do not understand why it says "Because all of the 
properties in the Dependant Role are non-nullable...": foreign key is nullable, all string properties are nullable, only the bool property is non-nullable....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the hint from BiffBaffBoff and adding some syntactic sugar for reaching the main location I finally got it running:

```
public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool flagMainLocation { get; set; }

    public int? mainLocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> ChildLocations { get; set; }
    public virtual Location mainLocation { get; set;}
}

public class myappContext : DbContext
{
    public myappContext() : base("myappContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(l => l.ChildLocations)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.mainLocationID);
    }
}
```

See the working example on github https://github.com/kranz/selfRefModel